# Linux] Setting Permission for Admin Group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I'm trying to set up my VPS to deploy my Rails app, and I constantly face these permission denied errors. I think the main problem is that I'm running as "deployer," who's in an admin group, and somehow "deployer" is not getting its rights properly. But this guess could be wrong.

```
deployer@max:~$ gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc
Fetching: bundler-1.2.3.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /var/lib/gems
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prefix the `gem` command with `sudo` because `/var/lib/gems` is owned by `root`. You could also take a look at [RVM](https://rvm.io/) which allows *really* easy installation and management of gems and Ruby versions.

Answer (score 0):

Just used "sudo" command to solve this issue...